# Flutter freezed data conflict with model data

Tags: flutter, riverpod, build-runner, freezed

I'm new to Flutter and following various guides to learn and, actually, after trying doing something simple by myself I found a weird issue and I don't know how to get rid of it...

These are my dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_riverpod: ^0.12.4
  json_annotation: ^3.1.1
  dio: ^3.0.10

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  freezed: ^0.12.7
  build_runner: ^1.11.1
  json_serializable: ^3.5.1
```

I create a small nodejs endpoint `/status` that returns a simple object: `{ message: 'success' }`

I created a model for the `Status`:

```
part 'status_data.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class StatusData {
  StatusData({
    this.message,
  });

  String message;

  factory StatusData.fromRawJson(String str) =>
      StatusData.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  factory StatusData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => StatusData(
        message: json['message'],
      );
}
```

I created a `Status_notifier`:

```
class StatusNotifier extends StateNotifier<StatusState> {
  final StatusClient _statusClient;

  StatusNotifier(this._statusClient) : super(StatusState());

  Future<void> getStatus() async {
    try {
      state = StatusState.loading();
      final status = await _statusClient.getStatus();
      state = StatusState.loaded(status); // ERROR (see below)
    } catch (e) {
      state = StatusState.error(message: 'Error: $e');
    }
  }
}
```

> ERROR: The argument type 'StatusData (where StatusData is defined in
> /my_long_path/lib/models/status_data.dart)' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type 'StatusData (where StatusData is defined in
> /my_long_path/lib/application/state/status_state.freezed.dart)'.

I created a `Status_state`:

For some reason here the `import` for my `StatusData` model is "grey", not used... It looks like it is using `StatusData` coming from some generated file...

```
@freezed
abstract class StatusState with _$StatusState {
  const factory StatusState() = Initial;
  const factory StatusState.loading() = Loading;
  const factory StatusState.loaded(StatusData status) = StatusData;
  const factory StatusState.error({String message}) = Error;
}
```

I created the `Status_client` to fetch data:

```
class StatusClient {
  Future<StatusData> getStatus() async {
    Response response =
        await dio.get('https://my-api.com/status');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      StatusData status = StatusData.fromJson(response.data);
      return status;
    }
    throw response;
  }
}
```

And finally the `Status_provider`:

```
final statusClientProvider = Provider<StatusClient>((ref) => StatusClient());

final statusNotifierProvider = StateNotifierProvider(
  (ref) => StatusNotifier(ref.watch(statusClientProvider)),
);
```

I also executed the command `flutter pub run build_runner serve --delete-conflicting-outputs` to generate the files.

Also in my UI, withing the `Consumer`, when the state is `loaded` I have an error:

`loaded: (status) => HomePageLoaded(status: status),`

The error is identical at the one wrote above...

Can someone explain what is wrong with my implementation so that I can get better on it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the name of the redirected Construcor

```
 const factory StatusState.loaded(StatusData status) = StatusData;
```

to

```
const factory StatusState.loaded(StatusData status) = StatusLoaded; // or make it private _StatusData
```

and re-run build runner